# PHP for each, use specific key's value

Tags: php, foreach

I am using `foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {` But dont know how to do something if $key is something specific then use its value.

I have read official documentation and few articles here cant find example of this.

I need something like:

```
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key="something"){
echo $value;
    //do something with that specifics key value
    }
```

Code above is "doing something" always because one of the keys "is something" and it takes last value of that array and echo it. I need value just of that one key.

Comment: Change `$value = $_GET['something'];` to `$value == $_GET['something'];` in your if statement, the condition will always pass because its assignment not comparison.

Comment: @ROOT Yeah, i would down vote myself now if I could...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if()` should contain `==` which checks the value for you and it should be `$_GET['something']` not `$_GET`

```
foreach($_GET['something'] as $key => $value) {
if ($key == "something"){
echo $value;
 //do something with that specifics key value
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232).

Comment: @JohnConde Should I delete my question? I agree, i should notice this myself, been staring at it for too long, its part of bigger script.

Comment: @JohnConde but by this time almost 90% the questions are answered so how will the beginner gain reputations?

Comment: @ikiK Yes. It won't offer any value to future visitors and is not the kind of question Stack Overflow likes to leave around. Because it has received a close vote it has entered the close vote queue and you may receive more downvotes as people review the question.

Comment: @KunalRaut There's hundreds of non-typo questions asked every day. There's plenty of questions to earn reputation on.

Comment: @JohnConde Well i cant delete it cose it has answer, I did vote myself for closing.